# How do I create KeyPoints to compute SIFT?

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I am using OpenCV-Python.

I have identified corner points using `cv2.cornerHarris`. The output is of type `dst`.

I need to compute SIFT features of the corner points. The input to `sift.compute()` has to be of the type `KeyPoint`.

I'm not able to figure out how to use `cv2.KeyPoint()`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Harris detector return dst, which have same shape with your image. Harris mark on dst where it think the corner. So, you have to extract keypoint from dst.

```
def harris(self, img):
    '''
    Harris detector
    :param img: an color image
    :return: keypoint, image with feature marked corner
    '''

    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_img = np.float32(gray_img)
    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray_img, 2, 3, 0.04)
    result_img = img.copy() # deep copy image

    # Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
    result_img[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]

    # for each dst larger than threshold, make a keypoint out of it
    keypoints = np.argwhere(dst > 0.01 * dst.max())
    keypoints = [cv2.KeyPoint(x[1], x[0], 1) for x in keypoints]

    return (keypoints, result_img)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is absolutely perfect, worked for me ! this should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you totally got it wrong. 
*The output is of type "dst"* --> Please be mindful that **dst** which is returned by the function cv2.cornerHarris is a floating point Mat containing the Harris corners detected in the image.

A example of code which I used in python is here for computing corners in a image. You can use the return data and convert it to KeyPoints type. Note that key point structure is defined as [OpenCV KeyPoint Structure](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=keypoint) and each key point is specified by Image space 2d coordinates of type Point2f. Just convert each detected corners to Point2f and use it for your sift function.

```
#sample code to read image and estimate the harris corner. 
import cv2
import numpy as np


def cvComputeHarrisCorner(img):                                                             
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)                                             
    gray = np.float32(gray)                                                                 
    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)                                                   
    dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)                                                              
    img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]                                                       
    return img                                                                              


def main():                                                                                 
   img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')                                  
   cvComputeHarrisCorner(img)                                                                     
   cv2.imshow('dst',img)                                                                   
   if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:                                                         
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()                                                             

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                   
   main()
```

Instead of explaining all what you need here, I would direct you to this OpenCV Python tutorial which is very well written and explained in the trunk. Please go through them and you will gradually learn about the concept.

[OpenCV Python Tutorials](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html)

Comment: please include the code to convert each detected corners to Point2f